How to get the second child from a Cheerio selection?
I'm extracting content from HTML. Let's say my test setup looks like
const html = `<ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li></ul>`

const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false)
const results = item.find('ul li') // -> 3 results

Given the above I can extract the content from the first item: results.first().text(). Is there a similar way to get the text from the second (or third) item?

https://cheerio.js.org/docs/basics/traversing#eq?

A few ways:
import cheerio from "cheerio"; // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const p = console.log;

p($("ul li:nth-child(2)").text()); // => B
p($("ul li:nth-of-type(2)").text()); // => B
p($("ul li").eq(1).text()); // => B
p($("ul li").eq(-2).text()); // => B

// also possible but likely unnecessary:
p($($("ul li").get(1)).text()); // => B
p($([...$("ul li")][1]).text()); // => B

Cheerio's documentation suggests:

Most of these filters also exist as selectors. For example, the first method is available as the :first selector. Users are encouraged to use the selector syntax when possible, as it is more performant.

